# How do I refer to a char* value in a struct that is passed to a method with a struct pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, char, c-strings

I have a struct defined as :

```
struct B{
  struct B_test *class;
  char* value;
}
```

how can I print the char value if I have function passing a struct as parameter as shown:

```
void print(struct B* e){
  ...
}
```

Comment: How did you *assign* the value that you want to print?

Comment: The exact answer is going to depend on whether or not that `char* value` represents a string.

Comment: the char*value indeed represent a string, dynamically

Comment: Please provide a full example of your code.

Answer (score 3):

For example

```
puts( e->value );
```

or

```
printf( "%s\n", e->value );
```

provided that the data member value points to an array that contains a string.

Otherwise you need to know the number of actual elements in the pointed array.

If the data member value points to a single character then you can output it for example like

```
printf( "%c\n", *e->value );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void print(struct B* e){
    printf("%s", e->value);
}
```

Accessing elements of a struct through a pointer is done with the `->` operator, not the `.` operator.

Comment: Can you please add an explanation to your solution!?

Comment: Added a simple explanation, there really isn't much to say